# How to increase the height of footerrow in jqgrid

Tags: jquery, html, css, jqgrid

I am displaying the Summary on footer row of jqgrid..Now as per my need i have to increase the height of footer row by changing the css but i have no idea how to get it..i am populating the footerrow by userdata fom server side code..

I want to overwrite the css for footer on my page because for specific pages only i need to change the footer height ..

Here is my jqgrid footer row enabled code..

```
            footerrow: true,
            userDataOnFooter: true
```

Please help me .
Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use CSS like

```css
.ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-sdiv .footrow { height: 55px }
```