# Increase jqGrid Footer Height

Tags: jquery, model-view-controller, jqgrid, footer

I've got a jqGrid in an MVC application. I increased the font size by adding a custom CSS file with the style shown below.

custom.css

```
.ui-jqgrid,
.ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-view,
.ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-pager,
.ui-jqgrid .ui-pg-input {
    font-size: 14px;
}
```

That worked correctly. However, the problem now is that the footer of the grid has not expanded to show the increased font size properly.

[image: jqGrid Footer]

As you can see, the pager cuts off the page number. I've tried implementing the solution found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19873787/how-to-increase-the-height-of-footerrow-in-jqgrid) on StackOverflow, but that didn't change the footer.

custom.css

```
.ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-sdiv .footrow { height: 55px }
```

Would someone mind helping me out with how to increase the height of the jqGrid footer?

Comment: It's important that you always write **which version of jqGrid you use and from which fork of jqGrid** ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) 4.14.4, commercial [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) 5.1.1 or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7). I recommend you to try free jqGrid 4.14.4 by changing URLs to jqGrid files (see [the wiki](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/Access-free-jqGrid-from-different-CDNs)). By the way the **footer** is *above* of the pager, thus `.ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-sdiv .footrow { height: 55px }` can't help you.

Comment: Only if you **have to** use an old jqGrid and can't upgrade to new version of free jqGrid then you can try to solve the problem by using `.ui-jqgrid > .ui-jqgrid-pager { height: auto; min-height: 25px; font-size:14px; }` or just increasing the height of `.ui-jqgrid > .ui-jqgrid-pager` without increasing of `font-size` on the whole pager. You need increase `height` of `.ui-jqgrid .ui-pg-input` too, for example `.ui-jqgrid .ui-pg-input { height:16px; font-size: 14px; }`

Comment: Sorry about that Oleg. Here are the versions.

jQuery JavaScript Library v1.12.4
jQuery UI - v1.12.0 - 2016-08-16
jqGrid by Trirand v4.4.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this

```
$(pager_id).css({"height":"55px"});
```

Comment: This partially worked edbird88. The footer is now taller, but the controls like the one that holds the current page number, are not any larger. This means the page number is still cut off.

Comment: Thank you for the input everyone! You put me on the right path. Ultimately this is what solved it for me. I updated my custom.css to have the following contents.

.ui-jqgrid,
.ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-view,
.ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-pager,
.ui-jqgrid .ui-pg-input {
    font-size: 14px;
}

.ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-pager {
 height: 25px;
}

.ui-jqgrid .ui-pg-input {
 height: 22px;
}